# Microsoft Visual Studio Error database cannot imported uncompatible and unsupported sql server version

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, refresh

I have a problem with SQL Server table data. When I show the table data and then refresh it, I get an error which states the following:

> This database cannot be imported. It is either unsupported SQL Server
>   version or an unsupported database compatibility

My code has no errors. I use a MS SQL Server database file (sqlclient) for my connection and data source.

Comment: Could you post a sample of the code you're using, and versions of software. More details will get you a better answer

Comment: I only use insert query with 3 parameters into a table.  The table doesn't update too. I use microsoft sql server ver.11.00.2100

Answer (score 0):

Before importing check the database file and sql server version.

> No backward compatibility is supported in sql server.

You can try copying the script.In the SQL Server Management Studio, right-click your source database, select Tasks, Generate Scripts. Use this to generate the SQL script that will create and populate the objects in the database. There will be several options for selecting the objects, selecting data, targeting a server version, desired output, etc. The resulting script can be run on the target server.

Comment: Thanks for all.. Problem is solved. There is wrong choice when I select data source. And there is a db copy in a folder that my data connection point to it, not to my db which pointing to desired path based on query